# jqPlot Pie Chart - remove data label backgrounds

Tags: jquery, jqplot

See image below; the goal is to remove the background for the labels (i.e. transparent background). I've been up and down the jqPlot documents and API, trying various combinations of settings... even attempted to overwrite what I thought to be the source CSS class:

[image: jqPlot Pie Chart]

One point is that this only happens when I try to render a pie chart... any other type of chart automatically displays labels without a background. Here's the base iteration of my code, cleaned up from all the experiments:

**Pertinent includes:**

```
// excanvas.js
// jquery.jqplot.min.js
// plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js
// jquery.jqplot.css
```

**JQ:**

```
$.jqplot('PIE', [[["CE",14],["CNB",0],["CD",10],["BD",197],["PD.",9],["AO",68]]],
{
grid:
    {
    drawBorder:false,
    shadow:false,
    },
gridPadding:{top:0,right:0,bottom:0,left:0},
seriesColors:[\"#2D8659\",\"#862D2D\",\"#2D8686\",\"#2D2D86\",\"#59862D\",\"#B4B43C\"],
legend:{show:true},
seriesDefaults:
    {
    renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    rendererOptions:
        {
        showDataLabels:true,
        dataLabelPositionFactor:.75,
        shadowOffset:0,
        lineWidth:3,
        sliceMargin:4,
        startAngle:-90,
        highlightMouseOver:false,
        padding:10
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for all helpful replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

It works

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NYewy/269/)

Code

```
$.jqplot('pieChart', [[["CE",14],["CNB",0],["CD",10],["BD",197],["PD.",9],["AO",68]]],
{
grid:
    {
    drawBorder:false,
    shadow:false

    },
gridPadding:{top:0,right:0,bottom:0,left:0},
seriesColors:["#2D8659","#862D2D","#2D8686","#2D2D86","#59862D","#B4B43C"],
legend:{show:true},
seriesDefaults:
    {
    renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    rendererOptions:
        {
        showDataLabels:true,
        dataLabelPositionFactor:.75,
        shadowOffset:0,
        lineWidth:3,
        sliceMargin:4,
        startAngle:-90,
        highlightMouseOver:false,
        padding:10
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: IT SURE DOES. Thanks sir -- you've indirectly helped me solve the problem! Our previous editor globally set all DIVs to have #FFF background... I couldn't figure that out until I looked at the CSS in your example.